# Bookmark Maker By using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let bookmarks = [{
    bookmarkId: "bookmark1",
    name: "Learning Portal",
    url: "https://learning.ccbp.in/",
}, ];

var ul = document.getElementById("bookmarksList");




// validation and submit
let submitBtnEl = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var x = document.getElementById("siteNameInput");

    var y = document.getElementById("siteUrlInput");



    var siteNameError = document.getElementById("siteNameErrMsg");

    siteNameError.innerHTML = '';

    var siteUrlError = document.getElementById("siteUrlErrMsg");

    siteUrlError.innerHTML = '';



    // checking for site name

    if (x && x.value == "") {

        siteNameError.innerHTML = 'site name is mandatory';

    }



    //checking for site url

    if (y && y.value == "") {

        siteUrlError.innerHTML = 'Please provide valid URLs to the siteUrlInput';

    }



    //submitting if both present

    if (x && y && x.value != "" && y.value != "") {

        siteNameError.innerHTML = '';

        siteUrlError.innerHTML = '';

        var site = {
            siteName: x.value,
            siteUrl: y.value
        };

        console.log(site);

        makeList(site);

        x.value = "";

        y.value = "";

        return true;

    }

    event.preventDefault();

    return false;
});







// to show the updates list in HTML UI

function makeList(site) {



    li = document.createElement('li'); // create a new list item

    var x = document.createElement("p"); // create a new p item

    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); // visit button for click to visit url

    var div = document.createElement('DIV'); // div to wrap site name and button



    x.innerHTML = site.siteName;

    x.style.margin = "0px";

    x.style.paddingRight = "20px";



    btn.innerHTML = "Visit";

    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

        window.open(site.siteUrl);

    });



    div.style.display = "flex";

    div.appendChild(x);

    div.appendChild(btn);



    li.appendChild(div); // append the div to the li

    li.style.marginBottom = "8px";




    // append the list item to the ul

    ul.appendChild(li);





    return;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Jane Doe</h1>
    <form id="bookmarkForm" onsubmit="return false">

        <label for="siteNameInput">site name</label><br>

        <input type="text" id="siteNameInput" name="siteNameInput" value="" /><br>

        <p class="error-message" style="color: red;" id="siteNameErrMsg"></p>

        <label for="siteUrlInput">site URL</label><br>

        <input type="text" id="siteUrlInput" name="siteUrlInput" value="" /> <br>

        <p class="error-message" style="color: red;" id="siteUrlErrMsg"></p>

        <br>

        <button id="submitBtn">submit</button>

    </form>



    <ul id="bookmarksList" class="bookmarks-container"></ul>
    
</body>

</html>
```

When we run the code and input the website name in site name user input element and website URL in site URL they appeared visit button, in that visit button we click button the website we entered at in "site URL" user input element that website can be open by clicking visit button by using anchor element in JavaScript code

Comment: Can you clarify what is the question?

Comment: When we run the code and input the website name in site name user input element and website url in site url they appered visit button, in that visit button we click button the website we entered at in "site url" user input element that website can be open by clicking visit button by using anchor element in javascript code

Comment: The above is the question sir

Comment: Sir anybody please help me

Comment: Sorry, I've read it several times, and still can't find a question, I see a statement of some sort, but not a question...what is the question???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67568618/bookmark-maker-in-javascript-and-html

Comment: Question is at in above link