# Bookmark maker in javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

```js
let bookmarks = [{
    bookmarkId: "bookmark1",
    name: "Learning Portal",
    url: "https://learning.ccbp.in/",
}, ];

var ul = document.getElementById("bookmarksList");




// validation and submit
let submitBtnEl = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var x = document.getElementById("siteNameInput");

    var y = document.getElementById("siteUrlInput");



    var siteNameError = document.getElementById("siteNameErrMsg");

    siteNameError.innerHTML = '';

    var siteUrlError = document.getElementById("siteUrlErrMsg");

    siteUrlError.innerHTML = '';



    // checking for site name

    if (x && x.value == "") {

        siteNameError.innerHTML = 'site name is mandatory';

    }





    //checking for site url

    if (y && y.value == "") {

        siteUrlError.innerHTML = 'Please provide valid URLs to the siteUrlInput';

    }





    //submitting if both present

    if (x && y && x.value != "" && y.value != "") {

        siteNameError.innerHTML = '';

        siteUrlError.innerHTML = '';

        var site = {
            siteName: x.value,
            siteUrl: y.value
        };

        console.log(site);

        makeList(site);

        x.value = "";

        y.value = "";

        return true;

    }

    event.preventDefault();

    return false;
});







// to show the updates list in HTML UI

function makeList(site) {



    li = document.createElement('li'); // create a new list item

    var x = document.createElement("p"); // create a new p item

    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); // visit button for click to visit url

    var div = document.createElement('DIV'); // div to wrap site name and button



    x.innerHTML = site.siteName;

    x.style.margin = "0px";

    x.style.paddingRight = "20px";


    let anchorEl = document.createElement("a");
    anchorEl.classList.add("btn", "btn-primary");

    btn.innerHTML = "Visit";

    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

        window.open(site.siteUrl);

    });



    div.style.display = "flex";

    div.appendChild(x);

    div.appendChild(btn);



    li.appendChild(div); // append the div to the li

    li.style.marginBottom = "8px";




    // append the list item to the ul

    ul.appendChild(li);





    return;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Jane Doe</h1>
    <form id="bookmarkForm" onsubmit="return false">

        <label for="siteNameInput">site name</label><br>

        <input type="text" id="siteNameInput" name="siteNameInput" value="" /><br>

        <p class="error-message" style="color: red;" id="siteNameErrMsg"></p>

        <label for="siteUrlInput">site URL</label><br>

        <input type="text" id="siteUrlInput" name="siteUrlInput" value="" /> <br>

        <p class="error-message" style="color: red;" id="siteUrlErrMsg"></p>

        <br>

        <button id="submitBtn">submit</button>

    </form>



    <ul id="bookmarksList" class="bookmarks-container"></ul>

</body>

</html>
```

In this code we can implement these three points that are

1. When a new bookmark is added to the HTML container with id bookmarksList, the HTML anchor element in the bookmark item should have href attribute value as the bookmarked site
2. JS code implementation should use addEventListener to attach submit event for the HTML form element
3. JS code implementation should use addEventListener to attach change event for the HTML input elements

Please help me for this code. How to implement these points in code

Comment: Ask 1 specific question about something you are having trouble with. Remove code that does not apply to your 1 question. Explain what you tried. Questions like 'help me code this' will probably not get answered and might get closed. I bet those questions have already been answered on this site.

Comment: Because of i can't no to implement in code of these things. That's way i asked to implement in the code sir

Answer (score 0):

When a new bookmark is added to the HTML unordered list element with id bookmarksList, the HTML anchor element in the bookmark item should have href attribute value as the bookmarked site.